# HTTP: Multiple HTTP methods in the request

Tags: http, get

I'm trying to simulate behavior by sending two http methods on the same http request using fiddler, as below, any ideas?

```
GET http://test.com/home.html HTTP/1.1
Host: test.com
X-Forwarded-For: test.com/home.html
Connection: Keep-Alive

CONNECT proxy:22@test.com/home.html HTTP/1.0
```

Comment: An HTTP request only has 1 HTTP method. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: we face a malicious traffic attacking our website, when we captured this traffic we found that there's two requests as per caption in my question.

Comment: below caption from wireshark for more illustration:
http://i.imgur.com/FA4Tcnu.png

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question, then. [Request smuggling](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246928/HTTP%20Request%20Smuggling) is not a legit application of HTTP.